# Is there a way to stop my :active button from displaying parent's hover effect on ::before/::after?

Tags: html, css

When I click my button element with a class of .btn, the inside of the button displays the red bars on its top and bottom. I do not want this to be the behavior but can't figure out why this is the case.

As far as I can tell, I only have a hover effect on the parent element .project that displays its ::before and ::after pseudo elements (the same red bars I mentioned above). I want this to continue but just don't want the bars on the button when I click on it.

I have tried moving my :active pseudo class to various parts of my code to see if it may be a cascade issue, but it doesn't look like that's the case. I also placed the :active styles at the end of the code to make sure pseudo classes like :hover came before it (i believe if these were out of order there could be more issues). I even used the developer tools to force an active state (oddly enough the bars didn't show up then).

````
    <section class="projects">
      <div class="project">
       <h2 class="project__title">To-Do List App</h2>
       <p class="project__description">This project demonstrates my understanding of HTML, CSS, and Javascript.</p>
       <button class="btn btn--pos">Go to Project</button>
      </div>
     </section>

```CSS

    .projects {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: .625em;
    }

    .project {
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 1.25em;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: black;

      &:hover > ::before, &:hover > ::after {
       content: '';
       position: absolute;
       height: 10px;
       background: red;
       animation: fillin .3s linear forwards;
      }

      &:hover > ::before {
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       border-top-left-radius: 10px;
      }

      &:hover > ::after {
       bottom: 0;
       right: 0;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
      }

      &__title {
       font: bold 1.5rem/1.4 serif;
       color: white;
       text-align: center;
       margin: 0;
      }

      &__description {
       font: 1rem/1.4 serif;
       color: white;
       text-align: center;
       margin: .625em;
      }
    }

    .btn {
      display: block;
      background: transparent;
      color: white;
      padding: 7px 30px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      border-radius: .625em;
      margin: 0 auto;
      transition: background .25s, color .25s;
      cursor: pointer;

      &:hover {
       background: white;
       color: black;
      }

      &:active {
       transform: translateY(4px);
      }
    }

    @keyframes fillin {
      from { width: 0; }
      to { width: 60%; }
    }
````

Answer (score 0):

Just comment below lines from css code:

```
 &:active {
   transform: translateY(4px);
  }
```

Comment: I believe that would take away the button press functionality I am wanting. I just don't want those red lines popping up for this element. Any idea how to get rid of those but keep the functionality?

Comment: It will don't effect default button press functionality in any way, its just a css code, css changes the way button looks, not the functionality. Just comment the code